Creating a struct referencing itself in C using custom type
I would like to create a struct with pointer to the property of the same type.
Ideally I would like to go for something like this, but this causes compilation error:
typedef struct {

  int data;
  Node *next;

} Node;

Solution I'm going for in this scenerio is:
typedef struct Node_s {

  int data;
  struct Node_s *next;

} Node_t;

Is it a valid approach or could it cause any obvious issues?

This question is much simpler if you break it into 2 pieces.  First, build the desired structure without the typedef.   Once the struct is declared, add the typedef if you want.  But trying to define the typedef and the struct at the same time is causing unnecessary confusion.  (IMO, the typedef is completely unnecessary and should not be used at all, since every usage of it tends to cause confusion rather than providing clarity.)

It is a valid and idiomatic method of declaring self-referencing structures in C.
You don't have to introduce different names for the tag and the typedef name, the following is just as good:
typedef struct Node {
  int data;
  struct Node *next;
} Node;

There is no name clash because these names live in different namespaces.
Another valid method is like this:
typedef struct Node Node;
struct Node {
    int data;
    Node *next;
};


Nice, I somehow thought that using the same name can cause some problems.

It is not self-referencing only referencing the structure with the same tag or type.

@0___________ The type is self-referencing, the objects of this type need not be.
